# Collection stored in application session turns null

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, session

I built a server-client android application in which users are registering to server and every user profile is saved in DB and in collection pool that i'm saving in the application session.

The reason I'm saving all the existing users in the session is that the users is updated often about the other users. and reading from Google app engine data store that often will cost me a lot.

this worked OK for the first month but today that I have 1000 profiles on my session things started turn bad. all of a sudden the collection of profiles became null and I had to "reboot" the server for the profiles to load again to session.

I guess that my design of saving all the profile in the session is wrong. Am I right?
or something else might caused the null collection ?

Is there any design pattern I can use to do things right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the internals of sessions and how they are handled in GAE well enough but my first guess is that the session gets too big and it fails to serialize properly between the requests.

My suggestion is to use the MemCache for storing the list of users. A typical pattern would be to store the tables you need in a database (that would include the connection pool per user you mentioned). Then, on first creation of a session or whenever you actually need it, load the data from the DB into the MemCache.

Once it's cached you can use it directly without additional database queries. If done right this is very robust and shouldn't get you in performance trouble either. Just keep in mind that the MemCache can be purged by the system randomly so you need to ensure you load it from the DB if the MemCache hasn't been initialized or reset.